# Remove matched item from array of objects?

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array of objects like this:

```
var myArr = [
  MyObject(name: "Abc", description: "Lorem ipsum 1."),
  MyObject(name: "Def", description: "Lorem ipsum 2."),
  MyObject(name: "Xyz", description: "Lorem ipsum 3.")
]
```

I know I can find the matched item like this:

```
var temp = myArr.filter { $0.name == "Def" }.first
```

But now how do I remove it from the original `myArr`? I was hoping the `filter.first` can return an index somehow so I can use `removeAtIndex`. Or better yet, I would like to do something like this:

```
myArr.removeAll { $0.name == "Def" } // Pseudo
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's wrong with `myArr = myArr.filter { $0.name != "Def" }` ?

Comment: Because that forces me to create a new variable. I want to modify the existing `myArr` variable.

Comment: No it doesn't. `myArr` is still `myArr`. And this is a value type; you cannot mutate it in place! You will _always_ be creating a new array, even if you write a mutating `removeAll` method.

Comment: A `removeAll()` implementation is discussed here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/86581/removeallclosure-in-swift.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

What you are not grasping is that Array is a struct and therefore *is a value type*. It cannot be mutated in place the way a class instance can be. Thus, you will always be creating a new array behind the scenes, even if you extend Array to write a mutating `removeIf` method.

There is thus no disadvantage nor loss of generality in using `filter` and the logical negative of your closure condition:

```
myArr = myArr.filter { $0.name != "Def" }
```

For example, you *could* write `removeIf` like this:

```
extension Array {
    mutating func removeIf(closure:(T -> Bool)) {
        for (var ix = self.count - 1; ix >= 0; ix--) {
            if closure(self[ix]) {
                self.removeAtIndex(ix)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And you could then use it like this:

```
myArr.removeIf {$0.name == "Def"}
```

But in fact this is a big fat waste of your time. You are doing nothing here that `filter` is not already doing. It may *appear* from the `myArr.removeIf` syntax that you are mutating `myArr` in place, but you are not; you are replacing it with another array. Indeed, *every* call to `removeAtIndex` in that loop creates another array! So you might as well use `filter` and be happy.

Comment: Does  `mutating func removeAtIndex()` really create a new array?

Comment: @MartinR Sure. Try this: `var arr = [1,2,3] { didSet { println("did") } }; arr.removeAtIndex(1)`. The `didSet` is called, proving that the array has been replaced. Think of the variable `arr` as a shoebox; we've pulled the array out of the shoebox and put a different one in. That is how a value type works. A call to a mutating func of a value type instance replaces that instance with a new instance.

Comment: @matt: `arr[0] = 2` triggers `didSet` as well. It's not that I don't believe you, but if each assignment to an array element  creates an entire new array then that would make Array quite unusable for any serious work (imagine a linear equation solver with 1000 equations and 1000 unknowns).

Comment: @MartinR No, there can be efficiencies of element storage we don't know about (and there is every reason to believe that there are). It may be a new array without making any new _elements_. Nevertheless, the array reference _itself_ cannot be mutated in place. It is replaced every time the array is mutated through it in any way.

Comment: @MartinR "`arr[0] = 2` triggers didSet as well". Exactly so. That's not an argument against what I'm saying, it is _what_ I'm saying. Try the same sort of thing with a reference type and you will see that this is not so. Replace the `name` of a MyObject instance and the reference is _not_ replaced (and `didSet` is _not_ called). - You might want to look over my book's discussion of this topic: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#SECreferenceTypes

Answer (score 5):

Apple had added what you want in Swift 4:

```
var phrase = "The rain in Spain stays mainly in the plain."
let vowels: Set<Character> = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
phrase.removeAll(where: { vowels.contains($0) })
// phrase == "Th rn n Spn stys mnly n th pln."
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the objects using filter then loop through the array and use myArr.removeAtIndex(index) to remove each object. Using filter is doing exactly that. To understand what is happening read below. Matts answer is a much cleaner way to accomplish this since you're testing for the opposite match therefore each object is preserved unless it matches your value.

Loop through your temp filter array

```
if let index = find(temp, note) {
   myArr.removeAtIndex(index)
}
```

Comment: For-loop the only way to find the index?.. Is there an elegant closure for this?

Comment: `find` only works for simple arrays, not array of objects right? Couldn't get `find` to work with array of objects.

Comment: You're already getting all of the objects using filter then you can use find in a loop to remove each from the other array.

Comment: `filter` _is_ the "elegant closure" (and also is a loop, by the way)

Comment: Exactly, there may be confusion as to how each iteration is used and if he is wanting to preserve the original array? Simply testing for the negative gives the "deleting from array" affect if that's all he needs.

Comment: "elegant" is find method, because filter and else methods make new array.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to remove an object from an array that is being iterated, you should always iterate backwards as otherwise you will at some point work on indices that aren't valid anymore.

```
var myArr = [
    ["key":"value1"],
    ["key":"value2"],
    ["key":"value3"]
]

for index in stride(from: myArr.count - 1 , to: 0, by: -1){
    let x = myArr[index]
    if x["key"] == "value2"{
        myArr.removeAtIndex(index)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Older and thouroughly answered post and all, but as an anecdote to Matt's answer above, for the simpler case of removing a single element, you could also do something like:

```
extension Array {
    public func dropFirst(matching: (Element) -> Bool) -> ArraySlice<Element> {
        guard let at = self.firstIndex(where: matching) else { return ArraySlice(self) }
        return prefix(at) + suffix(from: at).dropFirst()
    }
}
```

Which short circuits as soon as it finds element to drop

where:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].dropFirst(matching: { $0 == 3 }) // -> [1, 2, 4, 5] (ArraySlice)
```