# Shorthand to test if an object exists in an array for Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift

Currently, I have an array of objects like this:

```
var myArr = [
  MyObject(name: "Abc", description: "Lorem ipsum 1."),
  MyObject(name: "Def", description: "Lorem ipsum 2."),
  MyObject(name: "Xyz", description: "Lorem ipsum 3.")
]
```

I am testing if an object exists before proceeding like this:

```
let item = myArr.filter { $0.name == "Def" }.first
if item != nil {
  // Do something...
}
```

But I'm looking for a shorter way to do this since I am doing this a lot. I'd like to do something like this but it is invalid:

```
if myArr.contains { $0.name == "Def" } {
  // Do something...
}
```

Is there any shorthand syntax I'm missing or a better way to do this?

Comment: How does this question differ from [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29678071/148357)? They look pretty much the same

Comment: Same array, totally different question. I'm asking for a boolean to give me if an item exists in an array. Other questions is how to remove it from an array.

Comment: I'm learning and picking at Swift. Seems like I have to everything the long way, remove, contains, find, etc. I've been spoiled by Underscore.js and was hoping there was something like it in Swift: http://underscorejs.org

Comment: I've also been spoiled by built-in lambda expressions in C# :(

Comment: But have you been so spoiled that you can't bother to read the documentation or learn the language?

Comment: Ok ok I'll extend the language :). I have been reading the docs but supplementing with learning from people too. Thanks for sharing really.

Comment: Found this awesome Swift library that is a port of Underscore.js that can do many of these things: http://www.dollarswift.org

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Why not use the built-in `contains()` function? It comes in two flavors

```
func contains<S : SequenceType, L : BooleanType>(seq: S, predicate: @noescape (S.Generator.Element) -> L) -> Bool
func contains<S : SequenceType where S.Generator.Element : Equatable>(seq: S, x: S.Generator.Element) -> Bool
```

and the first one takes a predicate as argument.

```
if contains(myArr, { $0.name == "Def" }) {
    println("yes")
}
```

**Update: As of Swift 2,** both global `contains()` functions have
been replaced by *protocol extension methods*:

```
extension SequenceType where Generator.Element : Equatable {
    func contains(element: Self.Generator.Element) -> Bool
}

extension SequenceType {
    func contains(@noescape predicate: (Self.Generator.Element) -> Bool) -> Bool
}
```

and the first (predicate-based) one is used as:

```
if myArr.contains( { $0.name == "Def" }) {
    print("yes")
}
```

**Swift 3:**

```
if myArr.contains(where: { $0.name == "Def" }) {
    print("yes")
}
```

Comment: Coming up next: the dismay of discovering that there’s a `contains` that takes a predicate, but not a version of `find`...

Comment: if contains(myArr, { $0.name == "Def" }) {
    println("yes")
} how to get the current object from array with this statement

Comment: @anishparajuli: `contains()` only checks if an element is present in the array. This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28727845/swift-find-an-object-in-array might be more what you are looking for.

Comment: @MartinR basically i am trying to remove object from a array...without the index..Can you help ?

Comment: @MartinR i succeed using filter method..but is that a good way?

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity  meanning of $0 ?

Comment: Thanks to the anonymous downvoter for reminding me to update the answer to Swift 3 :)

Comment: @MartinR sorry, I was having an optional array in the condition

Answer (score 2):

IMHO to achieve the desired behavior you would have to create an extension class to the array that would look something like:

```
extension Array {
    func contains(test: (T) -> Bool, action: (T) -> Void) {
        let filtered = self.filter(test)
        if(filtered.is​Empty) {
            action(filtered)
        }
    }
}
```

I don't have xcode in front of me so I apologize if i have a syntax error. However if you are using the often you can write it as follows

```
myArr.contains({ $0.name == "Def"}) {
   // Do something...
}
```

I would rename it as to prevent confusion in your code.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but won't `self.filter(test)` produce an empty array if none of the elements pass the test, therefore never being nil in this case?

Comment: I can update the answer seeing as one would just need to check the size of the array, although Apple now includes functionality that fits the individuals need.