# Swift how to check if textfield exists in array at Index

Tags: arrays, swift

I am new to programming...

I know this probably is the best way to do an Offline login page
but 
MYSQL users db (consists of usernames, passwords, id) is 'downloaded' from a php script to iOS device.That part works, and the users print to the console.

What I am struggling with is, checking the textfield where the user enters their username to the 'usersArray' to see if it exists at index[0]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shorthand to test if an object exists in an array for Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29679486/shorthand-to-test-if-an-object-exists-in-an-array-for-swift)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do here but I think you are trying to take the value of a text field and see if that value appears in your `usersArray`. Provided this is the case try:

```
let exists = usersArray.contains(usernameTextField.text)
```

This will give you a Bool that indicates if the username exists in your array.

**Side Note:**

Hopefully you are only doing some general testing at the moment but in case you aren't… *Please* don't send passwords in plain text and *absolutely* don't download all usernames and passwords even in an encrypted format to a device! Aside from potentially taking up a large amount of space on the user's device you would be making it very easy for unscrupulous people to crack every user password in your database!

Comment: yes, I am trying to take the value of the textfield and see if the value appears in my users array. the above code throws an error cannot call value of non-function type 'NSMutableArray

Comment: That is only part of the error message though it looks like You are using an NSMutableArray rather than an Array so change `contains` to `containsObject` and you should get the result you want.

Comment: continuing on your comment.
`let exists = usersArray.containsObject(usernameTextField.text!)`
I added in `print(exists)` and it prints false to console, even though the username exists. It seems my whole approach for logging into the device is incorrect.

Comment: Is the `usersArray` an array of usernames or an array of dictionaries with usernames and passwords in it? In the second case you need to make an array that holds _only_ the usernames as Strings so the text from the field can be compared apples to apples rather than apples to oranges. The other option is to loop through the `usersArray` comparing the value of the username to the text field value, this is the expensive route…

Comment: the 'usersArray' has both usernames and passwords in it. I think I'm going to have to make it look through the array (which isn't a problem, should have at most 15 users when app is ready, and users won't increase)