# Using filter to find key in array Swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift

How can I optimise code using Swift functions like the filter?
What I want to do is I need to find a particular key if present no matter what value of that key is in the below array?

Below method works fine for me but I think there is some better way to do it.

```
let arrDic = [["Key1": "yes"], ["Key2": "no"], ["Key3": "yes"], ["Key4": "Option1, Option2"], ["Key5": "OC1_OPTIONB"], ["Key6": "H1_OPTIONA"]]

for dict in arrDic {
    if dict["Key1"] != nil {
        print(true)
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/q/29679486/2976878

Comment: @Hamish Thanks, That's what I was looking for.

Comment: Applied to your case: `if arrDic.contains(where: { $0["Key1"] != nil })`

Comment: @MartinR Checked your answer in above link by Hamish and got it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
let arrDic = [["Key1": "yes"], ["Key2": "no"], ["Key3": "yes"], ["Key4": "Option1, Option2"], ["Key5": "OC1_OPTIONB"], ["Key6": "H1_OPTIONA"]]

let result = arrDic.filter { $0["Key1"] != nil }.first
```

I'm sorry, didn't notice an intentions, add then

```
print(result != nil)
```

or even shorter

```
let isPresent = arrDic.filter { $0["Key1"] != nil }.isEmpty
```

or even

```
let isPresent = arrDic.contains { $0["Key1"] != nil }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search for an item using custom matching with `contains`:

```
if arrDic.contains(where: {(dict) -> Bool in
    return dict["Key1"] != nil
}) {
    print(true)
}
```