# Issue with checking if the array contains an object

Tags: swift

This might seem as a basic question..but I'm confused regarding how to achieve this with the new swift syntax. On the click of a button on the collection view I'm having something like this....

```
    let productObject = productData1[(indexPath?.row)!]
    self.myArray.append(productObject)
```

Now when I click on that button again I want to check if `myArray` has the `productObject` already so that it will not be added to the array again...Hope somebody can help...

EDIT: productData1 is a type of struct Product like so...

```
struct Product {
    let name : String
    let id : String
    var images = [ProductImage]()
    var theRate : String
    var quantity: String
    var sku: String
    var prdCateg: String
    var prodDescr: String
    var mrp: String
    var prodcutImage: ProductImage?

    init(name : String, id: String, theRate: String, quantity: String, sku: String, prdCateg:String, prodDescr: String, prodcutImage: ProductImage?, mrp: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
        self.theRate = theRate
        self.quantity = quantity
        self.sku = sku
        self.prdCateg = prdCateg
        self.prodDescr = prodDescr
        self.prodcutImage = prodcutImage
        self.mrp = mrp

    }

    mutating func add(image: ProductImage) {
        images.append(image)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is what type of `productData1`?

Comment: It's a type of struct Product. Like this...var productData1 = [Product]()

Comment: This is well covered in Array documentation. Did you read it?

Comment: `Product` is a class?

Comment: Its a struct @SalmanGhumsani...I have updated the question...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33532399/1187415

Comment: did go through that very link before, @MartinR but couldn't get much help for my issue..and hence asked a question...

Comment: Either use `contains(where:` or make your struct conform to `Equatable` then you can use regular `contains(`

Comment: hmmm...maybe I missed something @vadian. `contains(where:` is what is came across initially and with which I was confused with..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shorthand to test if an object exists in an array for Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29679486/1187415).

Comment: Assuming your products have unique `id` properties just compare `self.myArray.contains(where: { $0.id == otherObject.id })`. If the result is `true` the object already exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are 2 solutions. The first one is more efficient IMO.

**SOLUTION I** - maintain additional Mapping Data Source

```
var myArray: [Product] = []
var myDictionary: [String : Product] = [:]

func add(newProduct product: Product) {

    // Add only if product isn't contained in datasource (Test in O(1))
    guard myDictionary[product.id] == nil else {
        return
    }

    myArray.append(product)
    myDictionary[product.id] = product
}
```

Memory motivation / consideration: The memory cost of additional data-source is relatively low because of the lazy manner that Swift language copies structs. Both array and dictionary hold the same instances of Products until their inner content is changed.

**SOLUTION II** (Less efficient) - use contains method of the collection view (Iterate the array every time

```
var myArray: [Product] = []

func add(newProduct product: Product) {

    // Test while `contains`
    guard !myArray.contains { $0.id == product.id } else {
        return
    }

    myArray.append(product)
}
```

Comment: I'll have to call this method where I want to add/don't add  the element to array right..?

Comment: @bws - Yes, call add(newProduct:) method wherever you need in order to add a new object to your array. As i've said, the first option is better imo.

Comment: Glad i could help :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the order of your objects inside `myArray`, one solution would be do use a `Set`.
First of all you'll need to make your `struct Product` compliant to `Hashable`. 
By taking a look at your struct we can assume that two products are equals if their IDs are equals.

```
extension Product: Hashable {

    var hashValue: Int { return id.hashValue}

    static func ==(lhs: Product, rhs: Product) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}
```

You redefine `myArray` as followed:

```
var myArray: Set<Product> = [] // Creating the Set of `Products`

// inserting product with id "123"
myArray.insert(Product(name: "name",
                       id: "123",
                       images: [],
                       theRate: "",
                       quantity: "",
                       sku: "",
                       prdCateg: "",
                       prodDescr: "",
                       mrp: "", prodcutImage: nil))

// Trying to insert product with id "123" but it already exists,
// It won't be added to myArray
myArray.insert(Product(name: "name",
                       id: "123",
                       images: [],
                       theRate: "",
                       quantity: "",
                       sku: "",
                       prdCateg: "",
                       prodDescr: "",
                       mrp: "", prodcutImage: nil))

print(myArray.count) // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you..

```
  let productObject = productData1[(indexPath?.row)!]

     let filteredArray = self.myArray.filter(){
             return $0.id == productObject.id
          }
   if filteredArray.count == 0 {
      self.myArray.append(productObject)
             }
```

Comment: Forced unwrapping is bad – `id` is not an optional – Using `filter` instead of `contains` is ineffective.

Comment: your solution also worked, @Bapu..but accepted the other answer since it was given in more detail...have given an upvote though...:)

Answer (score 0):

ProductImage should conform protocol Equatable. Then you can 
check is objects of ProductImage are the same, and accordingly is images.contains(image) before add new one.

To conform protocol you need to implement func == for ProductImage.

Something like

```
func ==(lhs: ProductImage, rhs: ProductImage) -> Bool {
    return lhs.imageUrl == rhs.imageUrl
}
```