# Loop over array and return TRUE if value exists

Tags: arrays, swift

I would like to iterate over an array and if a value exists, I would like to return TRUE.

```
struct Loops {
    var loopStep: LoopStep
}

struct LoopStep {
    var template: [Template]
}

struct Template {
    var stepType: String
}

let templates: [Template]  = [Template(stepType: "FORM_ONE"), Template(stepType: "FORM_TWO")]
let loopStep = LoopStep(template: templates)

let incompleteSteps = [Loops(loopStep: loopStep)]
```

I have tried this using `reduce` however cannot make this syntax work

```
let result = incompleteSteps.reduce(true, $0.loopStep.template.stepType == "FORM_ONE" )
```

Comment: Why not simply use `contains(where:)` ? – Compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29679486/shorthand-to-test-if-an-object-exists-in-an-array-for-swift

Comment: Offtopic: If you got fixed values, you should use an enum. That way, it will be a lot easier :)

Comment: Unrelated: Avoid plurals in struct and class names : `Loop` instead of `Loops`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to use `contains(where:)` to get a `bool` return value indicating whether an element matching a closure exists in the collection or not. Since `template` is an `Array` itself as well, you actually need to nest two `contains(where:)` calls if you want to find out if an array of `Loops` contains any `Loops` whose `template` array contains a `Template` with the matching requirement.

```
let result = incompleteSteps.contains(where: {$0.loopStep.template.contains(where: {$0.stepType == "FORM_ONE"})})
```