# Long form of this Swift syntax

Tags: swift

The following will compare the first element's id with compr's id, and return true if matched.
I am confused with {} of .first { } != nil syntax. How does the longer form of this pattern condense to to the following:

```
private(set) var arr : [Arrs] = [] 

func isPresent(for compr: Compr) -> Bool {
  Arrs.first { comp.id == $0.id } != nil 
}
```

Comment: `first` returns `nil` if it doesn't find anything. So if the return value isn't `nil` it did find a value.

Comment: `Arrs.first` doesn't compile. You certainly mean `arr.first`

Comment: It would be simpler to use `contains(where:)`, see for example [Shorthand to test if an object exists in an array for Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29679486/1187415)

Comment: Explain what `Arrs` is and I assume `comp` is just a typo?

Answer (score 3):

First, change the line to the following so it compiles:

```
arr.first { compr.id == $0.id } != nil
```

---

This is just using [trailing closure syntax](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html#ID102) for the [`first(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1848165-first) method. It can also be written as:

```
arr.first(where: { compr.id == $0.id }) != nil
```

But a better way would be to do the following:

```
arr.contains { compr.id == $0.id }
```