# How do I safely remove items from an array in a for loop?

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop

Full disclose, this is for a homework question:

> It should have a private property of type [Circle]. An array of circles.
>   The method should remove any circles that have a radius larger than
>   the minimum requirement, and smaller than the max requirement.

It seems obvious that I should use `removeAtIndex()` to remove array items that don't meet a condition determined in the loop. However, many have pointed out before the perils of removing items in a loop because of what I guess is a "iterator/index mismatch".

Ultimately I ended up creating an empty array and using `.append()` to push the values that meet the "good" condition to a `filteredCircles` array, but I can't help but to feel that this this doesn't meet the criteria for the assignment.

Is there a solution that actually removes the items from the array in a loop?

Comment: Start with the last index and loop until you reach the first. Removing items only affects the indices of the items that follow.

Comment: @vacawama How do I do that in Swift? the loop syntax doesn't allow for index-- like other languages, so I am not sure how to count backwards.

Comment: @vacawama Nm... just learned about `circles.enumerate().reverse()`. Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at [Remove matched item from array of objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29678071/remove-matched-item-from-array-of-objects).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the `FOR LOOP` is **not** mandatory (and I don't see this requirement in the quoted text) you should use the `filter` method.

When you invoke `filter` on an array you get a **new array** containing only the values that do respect the closure you passed to `filter`. **The original array is not mutated.**

```
struct Circle {
    let radius: Double
}

let circles = [Circle(radius: 1), Circle(radius: 5.1), Circle(radius: 4), Circle(radius: 10.8)]

let bigCircles = circles.filter { $0.radius > 5 }
```

### Why this approach is better than mutating the array in a FOR LOOP

1. Since `circles` is a constant, you don't have problems related to **multithreading programming**. If `circles` was mutable then other threads could change it while you are looping it with very scary side effects.
2. It's **less error prone**. You are not writing what the CPU should do, instead you are describing how the results should be. So less potential misunderstandings between you and the compiler :)
3. You are writing **less code** which does mean less potential mistakes.

These are some of the benefits of writing Functional Programming code.

Comment: I guess I should just try it, but does `.filter` actually modify the array?

Comment: no. that's why he assigned the return value to the circle variable (which would have to be declared using `var`)

Comment: @nipponese: No it does't. And it's a good thing because (for several reasons) `circles` should be a constant. But if you want you can make `circle` a `var` and reassign the result to the same variable.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate in @vacawama's answer:

```
struct Circle {
    var radius: Int
}

struct MyStruct {
    private var circles: [Circle]

    mutating func removeCirclesWithRadiusWithin(range: Range<Int>) {
        for index in (circles.startIndex..<circles.endIndex).reverse() {
            if range.contains(circles[index].radius) {
                circles.removeAtIndex(index)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to use `Double` for your `Circle`'s `radius`, but want to keep the nice syntax:

```
struct Circle {
    var radius: Double
}

struct MyStruct {
    private var circles: [Circle]

    mutating func removeCirclesWithRadiusWithin<I: IntervalType where I.Bound == Double>(interval: I) {
        for index in (circles.startIndex..<circles.endIndex).reverse() {
            if interval.contains(circles[index].radius) {
                circles.removeAtIndex(index)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you are changing the contents of a stored property, within a struct.
Therefore if you declared an instance of `MyStruct` using `let`, you could not use this method.