# How to filter array of objects swift 4 then remove after

Tags: swift, for-loop

I want to avoid getting this error [image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H50iH.png)

which is INDEX out of range. Im trying to loop through an array but when I find something I want to remove , I delete it yet the .count of the array remains the same for that iteration of the for loop , how can I fix this?

here is console when run

```
test i:0  count: 3
test i:1  count: 3
test i:2  count: 2
```

yet the to: in

```
    for i in stride(from: 0, to: count, by: 1)
```

still seems to be 3...

Can Someone show me how to filter this array or loop through and remove? as long as it works i dont care what it is

Comment: Iterate in reverse to avoid this problem. Or filter the array instead of using a `for` loop.

Comment: Use filter: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35101099/1187415, https://stackoverflow.com/q/28323848/1187415

Comment: @rmaddy how can I filter my array to get out all the objects that have a .isSquadPlaylist = true

Comment: Update your question with relevant code fully demonstrating your issue.

Comment: @Zack The expression in the right side of a `for` loop is evaluated only once, prior to the first iteration. Your expression `stride(from: 0, to: count, by: 1)` will be evaluated to produce a [`StrideTo`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/strideto) instance (which is a kind of [`Sequence`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence)). Further changes to `count` won't effect the `for` loop, because it's iterating this existing sequence.

Comment: @Zack Similarly, the variable `i` is being assigned once at the start of every loop iteration, given the value of the result of calling `next()` on the sequence's iterator. Changing `i` won't have an effect from one iteration to the next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `filter`:

```
let filteredImages = images.filter { $0.someproperty == whatYouWant }
```

Mutating `for`-loops are something you want to avoid. Filtering is much safer.

Comment: See also the answer by @Krunal here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39974838/swift-3-array-remove-more-than-one-item-at-once-with-removeat-i